# How to move the ID of one element to another using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a slide show of icons. All the icons are in one class. Another style class called "active" will have an ID and represents the current picture. Clicking the left or right button should change the style of the active class.

```js
const leftArrow = document.getElementById('left-arrow');
const activeImg = document.getElementById('active') const nextImg = activeImg.nextElementSibling; // Handle left click leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function(){ activeImg.classList.remove('active');
nextImg.classList.add('active');
return nextImg
});
```

```css
.icon-container i {
  font-size: 150px;
  position: relative;
  left: 12rem;
  top: 12rem;
  z-index: -10;
  display: none;
}

#active {
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: .5s;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(238, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="object-container">

  <div class="icon-container">
    <i class="fa fa-car" id="active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plane"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-ship"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-buttons">
    <a href="" class="right-arrow" id="right-arrow"></a>
    <a href="" class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click the left arrow, nothing happens. I've also tried with the right arrow but that doesnt even show the cursor pointer so I don't know where I went wrong there. I've played around with z-index and display types but the buttons don't seem to be working?

Thanks

Comment: Consider opening dev tools, and look out for any errors. Errors are useful info.

Comment: Your title says ID but your question talks about classes. Which is it?

Comment: ID has to be unique. So transfering it from one element to another is not just a bad use but logically nearly impossible. It would be smarter and easier to try to transfer a class as you can call a specific elemnt by its ID. Callign a specific element without it having an unique ID is way harder.

Comment: @tacoshy Err, it is argubably bad practice but *nearly impossible* is highly overstating it.  It is easy to move ids.  https://jsfiddle.net/71rj6q3v/

Comment: @Taplar its not impossible to do it. But its ways harder to call the right element in a possibel changign eviroement. Unless the element has an unique class, in that case it could have an ID in the first place.

Comment: Difficulty is a variable.  If you are talking about a set of elements that you are wanting to shift an id amongst, then finding the current position of an id amongst those elements is super easy.  And moving it to the next or previous is at that point, also easy.  @tacoshy

Comment: @Taplar I'm very awrae on how to pass ID'S and classes. However the inital point still stands. Would be way easier to pass a class to unique ID's  as you have no troubles to select the correct element if the content changes. Otehrwise you have to hardcode for a specific cases and readjust the code if that case changes.

Comment: I completely disagree.  Within the context of a set of elements that you want to shift an identifier between, be it a unique class or unique id, giving them all unique ids complicates the matter, as without a shared class your selector to get the set has to account for every possible distinct value.  You're over complicating the concept. @tacoshy

Comment: Any ideas on how to actually move the ID then? The ID has a specific style so i want that style to be transferred to the next element once an arrow button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a class name and not an id. Here's how you can do that:

https://jsfiddle.net/sauz07d5/1

```html
 <div class="object-container">

    <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-car active"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-plane"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-ship"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-buttons">
        <button class="right-arrow" id="right-arrow"></button>
        <button class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow"></button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.icon-container i{
font-size: 150px;
position: relative;
left: 12rem;
top: 12rem;
z-index: -10;
display: none;
}



.left-arrow, .right-arrow{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
transition: .5s;
float: left;
box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(238, 0, 0, 0.5);
cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
z-index: 10 !important;
display: flex !important;
}
```

```js
const leftArrow = document.getElementById('left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.getElementById('right-arrow');



// Handle left click

var element = document.querySelector(".icon-container")

function slideNext() {
let currentImg = document.querySelector(".active");
let nextImg = currentImg.nextElementSibling ? currentImg.nextElementSibling : element.children[0];

currentImg.classList.remove("active");
nextImg.classList.add("active");
}

function slidePrevious() {
let currentImg = document.querySelector(".active");
let previousImg = currentImg.previousElementSibling ? currentImg.previousElementSibling : element.children[element.children.length - 1];

currentImg.classList.remove("active");
previousImg.classList.add("active");
}


leftArrow.addEventListener('click', slideNext);
leftArrow.addEventListener('touch', slideNext);

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', slidePrevious);
rightArrow.addEventListener('touch', slidePrevious);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var icons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.icon-container .fa')];

function adjustActive (adjustment) {
  var current = icons.find(it => it.id === 'active');
  var currentIndex = icons.indexOf(current);
  var nextIndex = (currentIndex + adjustment) % icons.length;
  
  if (nextIndex < 0) nextIndex = icons.length - 1;
  
  current.removeAttribute('id');
  icons[nextIndex].id = 'active';
}

document.querySelector('#left-arrow').addEventListener('click', e => adjustActive(-1));
document.querySelector('#right-arrow').addEventListener('click', e => adjustActive(1));
```

```css
#active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="object-container">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <i class="fa fa-car" id="active">Car</i>
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle">Bike</i>
    <i class="fa fa-plane">Plane</i>
    <i class="fa fa-ship">Ship</i>
    <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet">Jet</i>
    <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle">Shuttle</i>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-buttons">
    <a href="#" class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="right-arrow" id="right-arrow">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

While it is typically preferable to move classes around, you can (if you must) move ids around.  The example above uses the id to find the active element, and using the position of the active element in the array of elements, it finds the next element by adjusting the current index.  Then it is a simple matter of removing the id from the old current and putting it on the new current.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `active` as an ID, you should use it as a class, like so:

```html
<div class="icon-container">
  <i class="fa fa-car active"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plane"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ship"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle"></i>
</div>
```

Just create click listeners for the left and right buttons and remove the `active class` from the current item and add it to its previous or next sibling.

Or, if you consider its not worth the time to create your own implementation you can also use an already available one like [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarou)